# Google Cloud Function: behaviour when --max-instances reached

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I’m learning to work with Cloud Functions (and Cloud Run) and would like to know it’s behaviour when (HTTP triggered) function already running at Max instances capacity and more HTTP requests come-in

1)
Here’s my function basic code (simple function with approx. 1000ms execution time per invocation):

```py
ctr = 0
def hello_world(request):
    global ctr
    print("hello_world(): "+str(ctr))
    ctr=ctr+1
    time.sleep(10)
    response = flask.Response("success::", 200)
    return response
```

2)
deployed this function with flag `--max-instances=1` (just to ensure no new VM instances come up to handle concurrent requests)

3)
and then send 5 concurrent results

From what I observe, only one of the requests get processed. Other 4 requests just dropped (client received HTTP status code 500, and no trace for these dropped requests in Stackdriver Logging either)

In the link here  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances it says:

> In that case, incoming requests queue for up to 60 seconds. During this 60 second window, if an instance finishes processing a request, it becomes available to process queued requests. If no instances become available during the 60 second window, the request fails.

Based on which I expected, that while one request is being handled, others would be queued up for max 60 seconds. Therefore, all 5 requests should have been processed (or at-least >1 requests if not all 5!). However actual behaviour that I'm seeing is different from this.

Can someone explain pls.

**UPDATE-1**: It seems the fix has been released and [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#exceeding_max_instances) updated

1) It still continued to return `status code 500` during initial colds start (when no instances running) for some of the concurrent requests.. EXPECTED I suppose

2) Also, temporarily exceeded `max-instances=1` during very initial bursts of 10 requests, launching upto 4 instances AND successfully server all 4 requests.
[image: # Instances]

3) thereafter, # instanced did come down to respect --max-instances=1`settings and all but one requests returned with`status code 429`

Comment: I don't have explanation (that's why I can't answer, only comment!) except the Beta status of this feature. However, I observe the same strange behavior with another product in Alpha when I set the max-instance param. Maybe the same type of issue. I recommend you to open an issue in the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this. Interestingly if I put a 1s delay between requests that take 10s to complete, it works as expected. Seems like the issue is with the speed at which the requests initially come in. I've filed an issue internally and will follow up here.

Comment: yeah it seems, after adding *certain* delay, the subsequent request seem to have been processed. Thx for filing internal issue.. is there any way to track the progress ? or do you mind posting here.. and what's the *expected bevaior*.. by what logic concurent requests are expected to be in Pending queue & how long ? and is there any way to control this through deploy parameters ? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) engineering team is now aware of this and they will proceed to change the documentation to reflect the changes made to the feature still in active development. Stay tuned for the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#exceeding_max_instances), the update will come shortly =). Thank you for noticing this with your tests!

Aside from this, and as a suggestion from the team, if you are interested on queuing jobs, it is recommended to use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/)

Comment: It seems fix has been release & doc updated.. see my UPDATE-1 above in the original query. Look all fine now!